# T SQL Loop through tables and update field

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using MS SQL Server I have the below SQL that updates a table that begins with `'tbl_Test%'`.

However, I have the situation where I can have multiple tables beginning with the name `'tbl_Test%'`.  How would I modify the code so it will loop through and update all the `tbl_Test%` tables?  At the moment it only updates the first one.

```
DECLARE @NSQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @SOURCETABLE NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @SOURCETABLE = TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'tbl_Test%' AND TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'

SET @NSQL = 'UPDATE [' + @SOURCETABLE + '] SET [WEEKSTART] = CONVERT(NVARCHAR,convert(datetime, LEFT(WEEKSTART,10), 104),112)'

--PRINT @NSQL

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @NSQL
```

Comment: Look into CURSOR commands to loop through all the tables and execute on each.

Comment: I don't think you necessarily need a loop. See one of the various questions on SO about selecting a comma-delimited string (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/how-to-concatenate-text-from-multiple-rows-into-a-single-text-string-in-sql-serv)), use a semicolon instead of a comma as your delimiter, and you can build a whole series of statements directly into `@NSQL`.

Comment: Also note that your `LIKE` expression will match tables that begin with, for instance, `tblxTest` too. To match a literal underscore, use an operand starting with `tbl[_]Test` instead. Finally, it's a good idea to specify the schema (`TABLE_SCHEMA` from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`) in each of your `UPDATE` statements.

Comment: What are you attempting to do?  Why are you using string operations on date/time values?  Is dynamic SQL really necessary?  Why do you have multiple tables with the same columns?

Comment: @GordonLinoff because its an ETL load and I'm loading them dynamically

Answer (score 1):

I got it working using the below:

```
DECLARE @NSQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @SOURCETABLE NVARCHAR(MAX) 

DECLARE test_cursor CURSOR FOR 

SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'tbl_Test________________%' AND TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'

OPEN test_cursor  
FETCH NEXT FROM test_cursor INTO @SOURCETABLE

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  

SET @NSQL = 'UPDATE [' + @SOURCETABLE + '] SET [WEEKSTART] = CONVERT(NVARCHAR,convert(datetime, LEFT(WEEKSTART,10), 104),112)'

--PRINT @NSQL

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @NSQL

FETCH NEXT FROM test_cursor INTO @SOURCETABLE


END 

CLOSE test_cursor  
DEALLOCATE test_cursor
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need somethin like that :

```
DECLARE @NSQL NVARCHAR(MAX)=''

SELECT
    @NSQL = @NSQL+CHAR(13)+'UPDATE '+INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES.TABLE_NAME+' SET [WEEKSTART] = CONVERT(NVARCHAR,convert(datetime, LEFT(WEEKSTART,10), 104),112);'
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'tbl_Test________________%'
AND TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'

PRINT(@NSQL)
EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @NSQL
```

Comment: You should add a semicolon at the end of the line. It will probably work like this but much cleaner to end your statements.

Comment: @SeanLange You are absolutely right. I have missed it.Thanks for double check.